# Can tmux highlight (change color) on control key (send-prefix) event?

Tags: linux, tmux

Is it possible to highlight the status line or somehow visualize that I'm in command mode.

Could I create an extra binding action for `c-b`? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by use of conditional `?client_prefix`. 
Here's an example which changes color of the status-left part (usually containing session name) of the status line along with putting PFX literal in front to denote prefix is active.

```
set -g status-left '#{?client_prefix,#[bg=colour212]PFX.#[bg=colour202]#S,#[fg=white,bg=colour203,bold]#S}'
```